# ios - performSelectorInBackground is not working properly

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have an action, which should make some animations and during those animations, I want to push another view controller, but I want to keep animation running... My idea was do it using `performSelectorInBackground:`. So I run animation and than I call

`[self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(BGPushVC:) withObject:sender];`

Basicly it works, but there is problem, because the view controller push starts and after that, app crashes because of some stupid error, but when I call that function using classic `[self BGPushVC:sender];` everything is OK. Can you please explain me why is it doing those errors and how can I solve this? Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any UI stuff you should be in the main thread and not in a background thread. Save using a background thread for any intensive work(e.g. image processing) or an asynchronous task(e.g. downloading stuff).